# listview cell factory artifacts

Tags: listview, javafx

I am using the JavaFX ListView component and want to use a custom cell factory. When the dialog containing the list view is opened the items are rendered correctly. However, if I try to add or delete an item from the underlying observable list, the items in the list view are not rendered correctly. I will have cells duplicated or missing altogether. Here is the FXML for my custom cell:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>
<?import org.controlsfx.glyphfont.Glyph?>

<VBox fx:id="vbox" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="150.0" prefWidth="300.0" spacing="5.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <padding>
      <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
   </padding>
   <children>
      <Label fx:id="nameLabel" style="-fx-font-weight: bold; -fx-font-size: 14;" text="Mr Stephen Lowe" />
      <Label fx:id="mobileLabel" text="07798933862">
         <graphic>
            <Glyph fontFamily="FontAwesome" icon="PHONE" />
         </graphic>
         <font>
            <Font size="12.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Label fx:id="emailLabel" text="stephen.lowe@mypostoffice.co.uk">
         <graphic>
            <Glyph fontFamily="FontAwesome" icon="ENVELOPE" />
         </graphic>
         <font>
            <Font size="12.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Label fx:id="churchMemberLabel" text="Church Member" textFill="#388e3c">
         <font>
            <Font size="12.0" />
         </font></Label>
   </children>
</VBox>
```

and here is my custom ListCell subclass:

```
/**
 *
 * @author Stephen
 */
public class MemberListViewCell extends ListCell<MemberEntity> {

    @FXML
    private Label nameLabel;

    @FXML
    private Label mobileLabel;

    @FXML
    private Label emailLabel;

    @FXML
    private Label churchMemberLabel;

    @FXML
    private VBox vbox;

    private FXMLLoader loader;

    public MemberListViewCell() {
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(MemberEntity item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        if (empty || item == null) {
            setText(null);
        } else {
            if (loader == null) {
                loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/fxml/listcell.fxml"));
                loader.setController(this);
                try {
                    loader.load();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
                    alert.setTitle("Open FXML");
                    alert.setHeaderText("FXML Error");
                    String msg = "Could not load FXML for list cell factory. Inform software engineer. Terminating program.";
                    msg += ex.toString();
                    alert.setContentText(msg);
                    alert.showAndWait();
                    System.exit(1);
                }
            }

            nameLabel.setText(item.getName().getFormattedName(Name.NameFormat.FORENAME_SURNAME));
            mobileLabel.setText(item.getMobileTelephone());
            emailLabel.setText(item.getEmailAddress());
            if (item.isChurchMember()) {
                churchMemberLabel.setText("Church Member");
                churchMemberLabel.setTextFill(Paint.valueOf("#388e3c"));
            } else {
                churchMemberLabel.setText("Not Church Member");
                churchMemberLabel.setTextFill(Paint.valueOf("#d32f2f"));

            }

            setText(null);
            setGraphic(vbox);

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you set the graphic for non-empty cells, you need to set it back to null if the cell becomes empty:

```
@Override
protected void updateItem(MemberEntity item, boolean empty) {
    super.updateItem(item, empty);
    if (empty || item == null) {
        setText(null);
        setGraphic(null);
    } else {
        // existing code ...
    }
}
```